# Java JSON parsing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to get the hang of Jackson for JSON parsing by going through the toy examples here: 
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

The JSON:

```
{
  "name" : { "first" : "Joe", "last" : "Sixpack" },
  "gender" : "MALE",
  "verified" : false,
  "userImage" : "Rm9vYmFyIQ=="
}
```

I'm having trouble with the "Raw" Data Binding snippets:

```
1 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
2 Map<String,Object> userData = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), Map.class);
```

The value at "name" is {first=Joe, last=Sixpack}.  Surely the raw data binding can handle nested JSON objects, but I can't figure out how to access the value of first and last.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `Object` for that key (`name`) a Map? Just cast it and access it with those keys (first, last).

Comment: Jackson will do whatever it takes, and the key to `name` here will be a `Map<String, String>`. Just cast it when you `.get()` it.

Comment: @fge Do you mean the value to key `name`?

Comment: ((Map<String, String>) userData.get("name")).get("first");

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but This is how I did it. Please see below.

MainClass.java=

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

 public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    String jsonStr = "{\r\n" + "  \"name\" : { \"first\" : \"Joe\", \"last\" : \"Sixpack\" },\r\n"
            + "  \"gender\" : \"MALE\",\r\n" + "  \"verified\" : false,\r\n"
            + "  \"userImage\" : \"Rm9vYmFyIQ==\"\r\n" + "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    EntityClass jsonObj = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, EntityClass.class);

    System.out.println(jsonObj.getName().getFirst());
    System.out.println(jsonObj.getName().getLast());
    System.out.println(jsonObj.getGender());
    System.out.println(jsonObj.getVerified());
    System.out.println(jsonObj.getUserImage() + "\n");

}
```

}

EntityClass.java=

```
  public class EntityClass
  {
          private String verified;

private Name name;

private String userImage;

private String gender;

public String getVerified ()
{
    return verified;
}

public void setVerified (String verified)
{
    this.verified = verified;
}

public Name getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (Name name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUserImage ()
{
    return userImage;
}

public void setUserImage (String userImage)
{
    this.userImage = userImage;
}

public String getGender ()
{
    return gender;
}

public void setGender (String gender)
{
    this.gender = gender;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [verified = "+verified+", name = "+name+", userImage = "+userImage+", gender = "+gender+"]";
}
```

}

Name.java=

```
  public class Name {
private String last;

private String first;

public String getLast() {
    return last;
}

public void setLast(String last) {
    this.last = last;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name [last=" + last + ", first=" + first + "]";
}

public String getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public void setFirst(String first) {
    this.first = first;
} }
```

RESULT:-
Joe
Sixpack
MALE
false
Rm9vYmFyIQ==

Comment: What is EntityClass here? can you please add that too in code.

Comment: EntityClass is the class of getter & setters of all the properties of the Json.

Comment: Yes, that I know that it is PoJo class, since it was not posted on OP, please add it as part of an answer.