# Convert json array string to java object using jackson API

Tags: java, jackson

I have JSON string like below, and want to convert into Java object using jackson API.

```
 [
      {
        "Users": {
          "id": "1",
          "userId": "1424",
          "Firstname": "lms",

        }
      },
      {
        "Users": {
          "id": "2",
          "userId": "4527",
          "Firstname": "Matthew",
         }
      }
 ]
```

Can you please help me out.

Comment: try google, there must be a thousand examples just on SO

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371134/java-json-parsing-with-jackson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: I googled out and found the answer. Thanks all for help!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333106/jsonmappingexception-out-of-start-array-token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution, works like charm:

```
try {
                TypeFactory typeFactory = mapper.getTypeFactory();
                CollectionType collectionType = typeFactory.constructCollectionType(
                                                    List.class, Users.class);
                List<Users> usersList =  mapper.readValue(new File("list.json"), collectionType);     

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Google is your friend, this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) shows a good demo

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonInString = "{'name' : 'mkyong'}";

//JSON from String to Object
User user = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, User.class);
```

Comment: This is for single object. But in my case i have array. Please Do let me know how to convert  array into java object

Comment: Guess @Cubi has pointed out the solution for you then